# Text bubble randomly changing color on Galaxy S6's stock Messaging app on Android 6.0

Tags: sms, samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, color

I have a Galaxy S6 through Sprint and just upgraded to Android 6.0. Since the OS upgrade, my text messages have been seemingly randomly changing color. The text is always the same color, but the background of the bubble will change (yellow background on my messages, white background on incoming messages).

I thought initially the color change was caused by message status - sending, sent, received, etc. This does not seem to be the case, as once one turns yellow or white, it stays yellow or white.

I also thought that the colors corresponded to messages that I or my texting partner had not responded to (I sent 2 in row to her 1 incoming or vice versa).  This also does not seem to be the case, as I have been able to send multiple in a row without the color changing.

Do you know what the different background colors signify and how to turn them off?

[image: screenshot]

<sup>"Light-blue text bubble" anomaly compared to normal text bubble (dark green and blue)</sup>

Comment: @AndrewT. I've added a screenshot.  This is not 1 message that was broken into 2 because of it's length.  There are also examples of multiple replies from one party with none of them changing color.  The bubbles are yellow on my side when it happens

Comment: Enhanced messaging setting, and if the message is SMS or MMS will affect how messages are sent and received. Do you have enhanced messaging on or off? Was the blue message MMS, SMS, part of a group message?

Comment: enhanced messaging is turned off, and has been

Comment: The different background colors might signify nothing, and just a mere way of playing colorful in the app. Since the situation you describe is related to a specific app, and doesn't seem to affect other Messaging apps like Google Messenger, then what you're experiencing is probably a feature added to the stock sms app. Check your settings, there likely might be something to turn that off. @rogerdeuce

Comment: @rogerdeuce It may be for undelivered messages...

Comment: @Rexford I have gone through the setting and I am not seeing anything about crazy colors.  I was able to locate the "enhanced messaging" setting to confirm it was off.  Is there another menu I should be checking?

Comment: @RahulBasu It's not for undelivered, the messages that turn white are incoming.  But I have confirmed that the outgoing messages that turn yellow have been received.

Comment: is this really a stock rom from the galaxy s6? Or are you using a custom rom? The design looks really unusual for a samsung device in my opinion

Comment: @benjaminS There is a stock theme on the phone that has black background.  I've been using the same theme for 6 + months.  Text bubbles started changing colors with marshmallow 6.  No rooting or roming or anything like that going on, on this phone.

Comment: @benjaminS I did switch it back to the default theme and the colors still change

Comment: @rogerdeuce thanks for the info. I don't have a solution sadly - my best guess is that this might be the new behaviour - but that is just an assumption. I'd contact Samsung and ask if they consider this a feature and if it was intended. [Contact Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/mobile/cell-phones). You can link them to this question so things will be clear :)

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research I haven't (and from the comments, it looks like neither have other users) been able to find any resources on the internet regarding this curious phenomenon.

I am, therefore, forced to accept this as some sort of Easter egg from the Samsung developers' side (although, in my opinion, Easter eggs should *at least look nice*.).

This also means that you don't really get an option to 'opt-out'. If it really bothers you, you can [Contact Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/mobile/cell-phones#humanHelp) (although their 'Live Chat' feature seems badly designed since I couldn't get a representative to talk to me even after 30 minutes) or use another messaging app.

Comment: *comment by an anonymous user:* if you check your theme it most likely has an update that is needed. After I updated the os I had the same problem resolved by updating the theme in the theme selection (it was noted on red that update was available)